# WPF Background Worker and ProgressBar

Tags: .net, wpf, backgroundworker

So, I've got a wpf form, which goes out to a site, parses the html, and returns a strongly typed list of the 'href' values.  (yes, this is for my own website)

I am utilizing a backgroundworker to release the hangup of the UI, and render a running progress bar.

While it works great with just the first page of the site, if I decide to Recurse the site, the progressbar hangs, while the recursion is happenning, then once the recursion is through, the progressbar comes back to life.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?   And possible direct me to the proper usage of said backgroundworker with the progressbar... Basically, the progressbar should run while the task is being performed, but I assume based on the code that this really isnt the case.

Here's the code-behind for the window that this is being done in:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Threading

Class MainWindow

Private _previousCursor As Cursor = Mouse.OverrideCursor
Private _Spider As New Spider.SpiderIt
Private _Worker As New ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
Private _RunCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Me.workProgress.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    _Worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    _Worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    AddHandler _Worker.DoWork, New System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(AddressOf Spider)
    AddHandler _Worker.ProgressChanged, New System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(AddressOf worker_ProgressChanged)
    AddHandler _Worker.RunWorkerCompleted, New System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf worker_RunWorkerCompleted)
    Me.SiteParse.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub SiteParseKeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)
    If (e.Key = Key.Return) Then
        Me.btnParseAll.IsEnabled = False
        Me.btnParseSelected.IsEnabled = False
        Me.SiteParse.IsEnabled = False
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait
        Me.workProgress.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
        _Worker.RunWorkerAsync(New Typing() With {.Url = SiteParse.Text, .Recurse = Recurse.IsChecked})
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnParseAll_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnParseAll.Click
    Me.btnParseAll.IsEnabled = False
    Me.btnParseSelected.IsEnabled = False
    Me.SiteParse.IsEnabled = False
    Dim _TL As New List(Of DGTyping)
    Using New WaitCursor
        For Each Item In DG_SiteLinks.Items
            _TL.Add(New DGTyping() With {
                    .SiteUrl = Item.SiteUrl,
                    .SiteTitle = Item.SiteTitle
                })
        Next
    End Using
    Dim _T As New ParseLinks(Me, _TL)
    _T.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub btnParseSelected_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnParseSelected.Click
    Me.btnParseAll.IsEnabled = False
    Me.btnParseSelected.IsEnabled = False
    Me.SiteParse.IsEnabled = False
    Dim _TL As New List(Of DGTyping)
    Using New WaitCursor
        For Each Item In DG_SiteLinks.SelectedItems
            _TL.Add(New DGTyping() With {
                    .SiteUrl = Item.SiteUrl,
                    .SiteTitle = Item.SiteTitle
                })
        Next
    End Using
    Dim _T As New ParseLinks(Me, _TL)
    _T.ShowDialog()
End Sub

#Region "Get Site Links"

Private Sub Spider(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    'Do the work here, but need to get the value of SiteParse first
    With _Spider
        .UrlToParse = DirectCast(e.Argument.Url, String)
        .ShouldRecurse = DirectCast(e.Argument.Recurse, Boolean)
        .RecurseLevels = 20
        .SpiderIt(_Worker)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub worker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    workProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub worker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    EndRest()
    Dim _IL As List(Of Spider.Typing.InternalLinks)
    _IL = _Spider.InternalLinks()
    Dim _TL As New List(Of DGTyping)
    For Each item In _IL
        _TL.Add(New DGTyping() With {
                .SiteUrl = item.Url,
                .SiteTitle = If(item.Title.Length > 0, item.Title, item.Content)
            })
    Next
    _IL.Clear()
    Me.DG_SiteLinks.ItemsSource = _TL
    EndSync()
End Sub

Private Sub BrowseSite(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim _URL As String = DirectCast(sender, TextBlock).Text
    Dim _T As New Browser(_URL)
    _T.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub Window_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
    If _Worker IsNot Nothing Then
        If _Worker.IsBusy Then
            _Worker.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub EndSync()
    _Worker.CancelAsync()
    _Worker.Dispose()
    _Spider.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub EndRest()
    workProgress.Value = 0
    workProgress.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    Me.btnParseAll.IsEnabled = True
    Me.btnParseSelected.IsEnabled = True
    Me.SiteParse.IsEnabled = True
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = _previousCursor
End Sub

Partial Public Class Typing
    Public Property Url As String
    Public Property Recurse As Boolean
End Class

Partial Public Class DGTyping
    Public Property SiteUrl As String
    Public Property SiteTitle As String
End Class

#End Region

End Class
```

.SpiderIt() goes out the site specified, grabs the html as an HDocument (SuperstarCoders LinqToHtml), parses it for internal links, and throws them into a strongly typed list.   This is done in a seperate class assembly, and performs perfectly.

SpiderIt method and containing class:

```
Imports Superstar.Html.Linq
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class SpiderIt
Implements IDisposable

#Region "Public Properties"

''' <summary>
''' Specify the initial URL to parse
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property UrlToParse As String

''' <summary>
''' Should this recurse the internal links of the site
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property ShouldRecurse As Boolean = False

''' <summary>
''' Specify the number of levels to recurse
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property RecurseLevels As Long = 0

''' <summary>
''' Returns a message from the SpiderIt method
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public ReadOnly Property Message() As String
    Get
        Return _Msg
    End Get
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Returns a strongly typed list of internal links
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public ReadOnly Property InternalLinks() As List(Of Typing.InternalLinks)
    Get
        Return _InternalLinkList
    End Get
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Returns a strongly typed list of external links
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public ReadOnly Property ExternalLinks() As List(Of Typing.ExternalLinks)
    Get
        Return _ExternalLinkList
    End Get
End Property

#End Region

#Region "Internal Properties"

Private disposedValue As Boolean
Private _Msg As String
Private _Ctr As Long = 0
Private _InternalLinkList As New List(Of Typing.InternalLinks)
Private _ExternalLinkList As New List(Of Typing.ExternalLinks)
Private _DLer As New Downloader
Private _RCt As Long = 0

#End Region

#Region "Public Methods"

''' <summary>
''' Parse with the specified values
''' </summary>
''' <returns>Boolean</returns>
''' <remarks>Returns true or false, based on if it has completed, as well as a message
''' Spits out 2 strongly typed lists.  Both internal and external URLs
''' </remarks>
Public Function SpiderIt(ByVal _Worker) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 1 To 99
        _Worker.ReportProgress(i)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Next
    _Worker.ReportProgress(100)
    Dim _Doc As HDocument = _DLer.DownloadHDoc(UrlToParse)
    With _Doc
        If _Doc Is Nothing Then
            _Msg = "There is no document to parse."
            Return False
        Else
            Try
                Dim _AL = .Descendants("a")
                'Parse the internal links
                ParseLinks(_AL)
                _Msg = "Internal Link List Built"
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                _Msg = ex.Message
                Return False
            End Try
        End If
    End With
End Function

#End Region

#Region "Internal Methods"

#Region "Spider Helpers"

Private Sub ParseLinks(ByVal _AL As IEnumerable(Of HElement))
    Try
        Dim _Link As String, _D As HDocument
        For i As Long = 0 To _AL.Count - 1
            If _AL(i).Attribute("href") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not (_AL(i).Attribute("href").Value.Contains("//") OrElse
                    _AL(i).Attribute("href").Value.Contains("http://") OrElse
                    _AL(i).Attribute("href").Value.Contains("https://") OrElse
                    _AL(i).Attribute("href").Value.Contains("ftp://") OrElse
                    _AL(i).Attribute("href").Value.Contains("mailto:") OrElse
                    _AL(i).Attribute("href").Value.Contains("#")) Then
                _Link = UrlToParse & "/" & _AL(i).Attribute("href").Value
                If Not (_InternalLinkList.Any(Function(x) x.Url = _Link.Replace("//", "/").Replace("http:/", "http://").Replace("https:/", "https://"))) Then
                    AddInternalLinks(_Link.Replace("//", "/").Replace("http:/", "http://").Replace("https:/", "https://"),
                                     If(_AL(i).Attribute("target") Is Nothing,
                                         String.Empty,
                                         _AL(i).Attribute("target").Value),
                                     _AL(i).Value,
                                     If(_AL(i).Attribute("title") Is Nothing,
                                         String.Empty,
                                         _AL(i).Attribute("title").Value))
                    If ShouldRecurse Then
                        _RCt += 1
                        If _RCt <= RecurseLevels Then
                            _D = _DLer.DownloadHDoc(_Link)
                            ParseLinks(_D.Descendants("a"))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                _Link = _AL(i).Attribute("href").Value
                If Not (_ExternalLinkList.Any(Function(x) x.Url = _Link)) Then
                    AddExternalLinks(_Link,
                                     If(_AL(i).Attribute("target") Is Nothing,
                                         String.Empty,
                                         _AL(i).Attribute("target").Value),
                                     _AL(i).Value,
                                     If(_AL(i).Attribute("title") Is Nothing,
                                         String.Empty,
                                         _AL(i).Attribute("title").Value))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        _Msg += ex.StackTrace
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AddExternalLinks(ByVal _Link As String, ByVal _Target As String, ByVal _Content As String, ByVal _Title As String)
    Try
        _ExternalLinkList.Add(New Typing.ExternalLinks With {
                            .Url = _Link,
                            .Content = _Content,
                            .Target = _Target,
                            .Title = _Title
                        })
    Catch ex As Exception
        _Msg += ex.StackTrace
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AddInternalLinks(ByVal _Link As String, ByVal _Target As String, ByVal _Content As String, ByVal _Title As String)
    Try
        _InternalLinkList.Add(New Typing.InternalLinks With {
                            .Url = _Link,
                            .Content = _Content,
                            .Target = _Target,
                            .Title = _Title
                        })
    Catch ex As Exception
        _Msg += ex.StackTrace
    End Try
End Sub

#End Region

#Region "IDisposable Support"

Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
        End If
        _Msg = String.Empty
        _InternalLinkList.Clear()
        _ExternalLinkList.Clear()
        _DLer.Dispose()
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
End Sub

Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub

#End Region

#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: I am not sure, so I don't post this as an answer, but it seems that your function SpiderIt() is called in a modal way. Exiting from this function you start a loop to advance the progress bar, but at this point you have already finished the parsing. The same thing happens if you recurse, but of course more time is needed to complete the parsing and you could notice the delay in the progress bar. I think you should call the ReportProgress inside the SpiderIt function calculating the percentage of work done inside that function. (Will be good to see the relative code)

Comment: So I assume I should probably pass the _Worker to SpiderIt(), But, but how would this class get the return?   I will experiment

Comment: Looking at the actual code, you don't need any return from SpiderIt(), just pass the _worker when you call SpiderIt(), but, of course I don't have a full understanding of your code.

Comment: ok.  it still works doing that, however, it still does not progress per the actual work being done.  I'll edit the question to put in the class where SpiderIt is located.  Please look over the original as well, since that has changed slightly

Comment: You have a class and a function named SpiderIt

Comment: Really hard to tell when you don't provide the code that actually invokes the background worker.  e.g. there's not code that uses  `SiteParseKeyDown` which is the only method that invokes the backgroundworker.  Also, it appears that you're setting the progress incrementally to 100 right away (Top of `SpiderIt` method, the calls to `ReportProgress`) before doing any work.  If the work takes a while, it will appear like the progress bar would do nothing until all the work is done--which would seem like it "hangs".

Comment: siteparsekeydown should be pretty obvious in what it does.   if u look closer it looks for the return keyboard key being pressed...common sense wohld then dictate that obviously this is an event from some object in the xaml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer 'cause as a comment the text was too long.

Maybe I am missing something (reading the code in this format is a pain).

You are counting from 1 to 99 and report that progress every 50 miliseconds. In between nothing seems to be happening, I mean work load that would add some real delays. Then you report 100% and only then it seems to be actually loading the document and parsing which takes a while I guess.

Shouldn't you throw a ReportProgress() somewhere inside the ParseLinks() method. Of course you'll have to be able to calculate how many nodes you'll parse so you can report the progress at a pace which will coincide with 100% progress when the work is done.

Write another recursive method that only calculates the number of nodes ahead of time (that should be quick) and then armed with that number you will know the value to pass to ReportProgress() (that again you should call inside ParseLinks()) so you'll have a steady progress up to 100%. (and obviously you'll have to pass a reference to the BackgroundWorker to ParseLinks() to)

It may be difficult but nobody said it's going to be easy :D.

Cheers.

Comment: aye.   thought that would probably be the route to go... (which is what i am doing elsewhere once that list is populated)...  ill have to expirement a bit, but if i remember correctly....    the .decendants("a") is an enumerable intetface...there should be a count method on that that i could get the number from....possibly with some kind oh .where to only grab the internal links...

Comment: hmmm....  i will end up having to do that in another recursive function anyways....    that way i get the complete count of urls...    thanks...    will end up doing this after the holidays. :)

Comment: :)   You too.   So, I lied...  i jumped on today while it was fresh.   You guys are godsends I swear! LOL   Anyways...  works great as long as I don't have to recurse, once the recursion is enable it fails, so I think I am going to have to do a seperate recursive function to get a full count.   The problem with this is, if it's a site with a ton of internal links, it will slow it down incredibly

Comment: muah haha.   So, here's something that is kind of funky, but I think I am going to keep just the way that it is.  It's working, and working great for the non-recursive.  When I implement it into the recursion, the prgress bar starts over....  in fact, because of the recursion, it starts over multiple times...   but I kind of like this, as it shows that work is getting done, over and over because of the recursion.    Can you think of any caveats to keeping it like this, because I actually want to keep it doing this =)

Comment: No, it's perfectly ok. That's clearly a behavior that you and I have seen in many other products (software installations especially). It's a compromise, sometimes you have to do it and as long as it fits your new requirements it's perfect.